# Regex password validation add underscore like special symbol

Tags: java, regex

Password must contains :
1 Upper letter 
1 lower letter
1 digit
1 special symbol
Minimum 8 symbols

Here it is my regex:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@_$%^&*-]).{8,}$
```

But when i try to validate for example with password: Test_123 it returns me `false`

here is my code :

```
public class PasswordCheck {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CommonHelper.class);

    private static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@_$%^&*-]).{8,}$";

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    public PasswordCheck() {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
    }

    /**
     * Validate password with regular expression
     * 
     * @param password
     *            password for validation
     * @return true valid password, false invalid password
     */
    public boolean validate(final String password) {

        matcher = pattern.matcher(password);
        System.out.println(password);
        System.out.println(matcher.matches());
        return matcher.matches();

    }

}
```

I just try it to set new String in validate function with the same text: Test_1523 and return me true but when i post this string via rest service and pass it to the function returns me false

Comment: I check on http://regexr.com/ and regex it's ok, please could you post your code?

Comment: Did you set the case insensitive modifier?

Comment: Add a breakpoint on "matcher = pattern.matcher(password);" line inside validate method and see what is the value of "password" parameter. I just want to check if it contains any other character.

Comment: I go deeper into and realised that the problem is not the regex but the string coming from rest service. Still dont know why but when i format it like this:

byte bytes[] = pass.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
  String checkPassword = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
if (passCheck.validate(checkPassword)) {

It`s start working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

No matter if you are using regular expressions or other means to validate those strings - but please: don't push everything into one piece of code or regex.

You want to create code that is easy to read and maintain; and a single regex containing so much "coded" knowledge wont help with that. I have more than once used something like

```
interface PasswordValidator {
  boolean isValid(String input);
  String getErrorMessage();
}
```

To then create various classes implementing such an interface. And finally, you simply create one object per implementation class; and you can put those into some static list. And then validating means: just run all validator objects in that list. On fail, you can directly ask for the error message for the user (so you can tell him exactly what is missing; instead of throwing the whole rule set at him again).

Not saying that something like that is always required, but in my experience: password rules might change frequently. Hard-baking them into regexes is rarely a durable approach.